# How to cite several testimonies from the same House Bill in Apa

Tags: citations, essay, apa

We are attempting to cite several testimonies, both parenthetically and on the references page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://library.csustan.edu/jbrandt/class/apa-legal.pdf